# Can I connect an Arduino wifi module directly to my android phone?

Tags: wifi

I would like to use my arduino even where there's no wifi router. I've only found people saying that it needs to connect to a router, but isn't the phone like a router when it's in tethering mode? Do I still need a mobile internet connection or can I do it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phone running in wifi tethering (mobile hotspot) mode is no different to a wifi access point or router. So yes, you can use that.

Chances are though that you will need a mobile internet connection in order to activate mobile hotspot mode in the first place.

Comment: My Galaxy Mini 2 lets me turn mobile router while not connected to mobile connection. The matter's that the example sketches that I've seen by now are all something like this: connect to a router, get the ip, and then from android you put the ip and connect to the arduino. I'd like to skip the ip part: arduino connects to the mobile router, and (since when you connect to a router you need to send data back and forth from router to user and vice versa) they exchange data even if the mobile phone has no connection. Can I do this?

Comment: You need the IP. Without that you don't know where to send data. You may be able to find it in the tethering settings under the list of connected devices depending on the version of Android.

Comment: So I always need an internet connection. I thought it would have worked like bluetooth, since router and user need to talk to each other, but what you're saying suggests me I can't. Unless I can use the "internal IP" (don't know if it is its name), the one that is always 192.something. If I can use that, isn't it given before the connection to the internet starts?

Comment: An IP is an IP. Every device connected on a network needs one. The phone can hand one to the Arduino through DHCP. You don't need an internet connection for that, not if you can turn on mobile hotspot without one. It sounds like you need a crash course in how networks work. Browse around wikipedia a bit and learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Arduino UNO WiFi Board (http://www.arduino.org/products/boards/arduino-uno-wifi) with the built in ESP8266 chip then your phone can connect directly to the Arduino's network and you can interact with it that way.

With the default firmware, this board can simultaneously connect to a local WiFi network, and create its on access point. This is very handy because it means that you can connect and access its hosted web pages even without a WiFi router with no extra setup steps, or special configuration.

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants the opposite.  Not using a phone to connect to the ESP8266 module (as AP or captive portal).. but use the ESP8266 to connect to the phone and use it as an AP.

Comment: @whispers That could be, but the question isn't clear, and often when the question isn't clear it is because the OP didn't know that the other method was even an option.